# Is it possible to re-install a particular OS out of multi-boot operating systems?

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd, multi-boot, operating-systems

Background:

I am having 1 Tb hard disk and 1 Tb SSD.Having 4 operating systems installed (multi-boot) on them ( 2 Ubuntu and 2 Windows ). Out of 2 Ubuntu, one is on hard disk and one is on the SSD. Same for the windows.

Question:

With that being said, one of my windows ( one on the SSD) unexpectedly crashed. So is it possible only to reinstall that particular operating system and keep others as it is?

Comment: It should be possible. Operating System installation environments typically only modify the target drive, outside of the boot partition, but you have provided very little information.  The worst you would have to do is retrain your boot loader about your operating systems

Comment: But how it's done? Through BIOS? Because currently my definition of "crashed" is windows is loading but appears black screen after signing in.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's even not too difficult, though I recommend backing up your system first because any mistake will cause serious data loss.

Fist I would recommend that you remove the disk that has the two working installations to lower the risk of accidentally deleting the wrong installation. Then just boot from the Windows install DVD / USB disk and on the screen that prompts you for the target partition, delete the partition used by the faulty Windows installation, create a new blank partition and install Windows there.

The tricky part is that Windows always overwrites the disk's bootloader with its own, which can't boot Linux without going through multiple hoops and is generally not recommended in that case.

Now this splits into two cases -

1. The main hard drive, i.e., the one you usually boot from, is the second drive, i.e., *not* the one you've just reinstalled Windows to, in which case you don't need to do anything, just reconnect it as your main drive and boot from it and everything should work fine. The only possible problem is if the new Windows installation doesn't boot properly, in case you will need to boot up one of your existing Linux installations and use that to reinstall the GRUB bootloader - here are instructions on how to do this:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Reinstalling_GRUB_2

2. The main drive is the one you've just reinstalled Windows to. In this case unfortunately GRUB got overwritten by Windows and you will have to reinstall it. You will need a Linux Live CD / USB disk to boot into a Linux environment, then reinstall GRUB to the main hard-drive from there. Instructions can be found on the same page (linked above).

Good luck!